# Gorilla/mux: Image not displaying

Tags: go

I am new in Golang. I need display an image. I tried using Gorilla/mux.
But I am still getting Error:404. I thing may be the place where I used mux code is not correct.

Main func

```
    package main
    import (
        "net/http"
        "mytestsite/handlers"
         "log"
         "github.com/gorilla/mux"
     )


    func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/register", handlers.RegisterHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/sucess", handlers.Sucess)
    r.HandleFunc("/login", handlers.Login)
    r.HandleFunc("/list", handlers.ViewList)
    r.HandleFunc("/logout", handlers.Logout)
    r.HandleFunc("/edit", handlers.Edit)
    r.HandleFunc("/EditnList", handlers.EditnList)
    r.HandleFunc("/notvalid", handlers.NotValid)
    r.HandleFunc("/delete", handlers.Delete)
    r.HandleFunc("/listchoose", handlers.ListChoose)
    r.HandleFunc("/email", handlers.SendEmail)
    images := http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./frontend/images/")))
    r.PathPrefix("/images/").Handler(images)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8181", r); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("http.ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }        
}
```

Func which pass data to html

```
func ViewList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    viewModel:=viewmodels.RegisterViewModel{}
    user:=models.User{}
    dbResults := user.ViewDB() 

    //Cookies below
    cookieCheck := getCookie(r)

    if (cookieCheck != ""){
        err:=GetTemplate("list").Execute(w,dbResults)
        if err!=nil{
            panic(err)
        }
    } else { 
        viewModel.ErrorMessage="Please Enter Email Id and Password.."
        err:=GetTemplate("login").Execute(w,viewModel)
        if err!=nil{
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in html file

```
<td><img src="{{.Photo}}" alt="{{.Photo}}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"/></td>
```

Value of {{.Photo}} is stored to Db by following code:

```
ctime := time.Now()
uploadedfile := "frontend/images"+ctime.Format("20060102150405")+".jpg"
out, err := os.Create(uploadedfile)
```

SO value of {{.Photo}} will be like as follows

```
frontend/images/20160202171411.jpg
```

Comment: the image tag itself is 404'd?  or the whole page?  You also don't show where where Photo comes from. I assume it's an attribute of your viewmodel?  Is it a url?  what's the value of .Photo?

Comment: @David Budworth Page is loading. Image shows as broken image link. The image link is coming from the DB. When I take tdate image li

Comment: (Sorry accidentally tapped on post button..) when I take take inspect element image link is present there. But when I try to open the link it is giving me a 404. The link is stored in the DB at the time of image upload. I will add the code ASAP.

Comment: and you are running you app from whatever the part dir of frontend is?

Comment: also, just noticed.  you create a mux.NewRouter but never pass it to listen and serve.  you are currently mixing gorilla and stdlib http muxes

Comment: @David Budworth My main function is in root just where the dir frontend is. Can you please explain me how to pass mux to listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two routers here.

First off, the http package has a package global default handler called: [DefaultServeMux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-variables).  This is an instance of [http.ServeMux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux)

When you call [http.HandleFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc), DefaultServeMux is where that handler gets registered ([source](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=51688:51759#L1745))

When you call [http.ListenAndServe](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe), the second parameter is what handler to use for HTTP requests that come in on your specified port.

If you pass nil as the handler (like you do in your code), you are telling the http server to use http.DefaultServeMux

[Gorilla mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) is an alternative to http.ServeMux.  In general, you use one or the other.

In your case, you are registering your file server with a gorilla mux, but then telling http.ListenAndServe to use http.DefaultServeMux (by omitting the handler).

You can either register your file serve with the standard http library's default mux (via: [http.Handle](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle)) or change your function mappings to register with your Gorilla mux (via: [r.HandlerFunc](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.HandlerFunc)).

If you choose to use Gorilla (more flexible solution, but is not really necessary given your example code), then pass that instead of nil to ListenAndServe.

Comment: Thanks man. I had changed the code as you instructed. But the image problem is still there. Edited the question with the new code and value of {{.Photo}}

Comment: And when you start your app, your shell is sitting in the parent directory of `./frontend/images/`?  What is the photo url (img tag source)?

Comment: My photo path is stored in the DB. {{.Photo}} is meant to populate different images into a list. When I login to the list page it is supposed to show different photos which were previously uploaded. I managed to pass different paths in my db which were inserted at the time of photo upload. Hoping this is what you asked.

Comment: i mean, literally, what directory are you in when you run your app.  when you tell fileserver ./frontend/images, that means "from where i was when I ran my app", not "relative to my source code".  And I was asking for an exact example of a url (without hostname)... le: /images/foo.png.  The next step was to ask if you could (from your bash or cmd prompt) type ls (or dir) ./frontend/images/foo.png  and find it.   because, if not, you will get a 404